# Tizen Web Application : The screen blinks after adding Unity webGL

Tags: webgl, tizen, unity-webgl, tizen-web-app

I'm working on combining Unity Webgiel with Tizen.
The device I use is a Smart M8 monitor.

My order of work is

1. Build Unity WebGiel
2. Creating a Tizen Web Application (Smart TV 6.5)
3. Overwrite Unity WebGel file on Tizen project (Index.html changed)
4. Build WGT
5. Convert to TMG file
6. Install Tizen OS

It worked fine when running the Tizen Web Simulator Application (Samsung TV) in Tizen Studio.

But when I ran it on the Smart M8 monitor, the screen blinking occurred. This problem did not occur in the Tizen Web Application basic project.

What I'm curious about is

1. Is there a way to solve the blinking phenomenon?
2. I want to know how to WGT Unity WebGL, not how to overwrite the webgiel file on the Tizen project.

Please answer me

My order of work is

1. Build Unity WebGiel
2. Creating a Tizen Web Application (Smart TV 6.5)
3. Overwrite Unity WebGel file on Tizen project (Index.html changed)
4. Build WGT
5. Convert to TMG file
6. Install Tizen OS

Answer (score 1):

The screen blinking phenomenon can be seen when there are too much overhead on GPU due to heavy WebGL commands.

I think this phenomenon only happened on the smart monitor, because emulator could use PC's rich GPU resources, whereas smart monitor suffered from the limited GPU resources.

In conclusion, to answer your question 1, you need to reduce the complexity of your app in order to prevent the blinking issue. Hopefully a future Tizen version will fix this issue.